# Rendering G+ share button is not working?

Tags: google-plus

Actually I'm not so sure if G+ is still alive around. But my webpage requires to render such a button, and I can easily Google around to find this snippet of code from the official Google documentation page (https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/#example-async-defer):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Share Demo: Deferred execution with language code</title>
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com" />
</head>
<body>
<g:plus action="share"></g:plus>

<script>
  window.___gcfg = {
    lang: 'en-US',
    parsetags: 'onload'
  };
</script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

however it's not working, not any rendered.
I've almost assumed that it's simply the signal of death. Yes G+ is dead, isn't it? It's strange that the shared link sample still works partially (it's partial because it seems not able to load my shared link, always reports invalid link):

```
<a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url={URL}"
   onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href,
 '', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=600');return false;">
  <img src="https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/gplus-64.png" 
       alt="Share on Google+"/></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google+ share button is no longer supported.

> Web integrations, such as Plugins and Interactive Posts, have stopped serving.

https://developers.google.com/+/integrations-shutdown

Comment: Thanks, it's not easy to dig back the official statement.